# Is it correct to consider dissolving HCl gas in water as oxidation –reduction process?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

References define oxidation –reduction process as change in oxidation number ,**Accordingly it is not appropriate to describe the mentioned  process as oxidation –reduction** because there is  no change in oxidation number of atoms **and it is not a chemical reaction** .

But the teacher consider it as oxidation –reduction reaction **because HCl gas** **ionize in water** .
Iam confused , so any idea will greatly help.

Comment: No. The oxidation state of neither H nor Cl changes so it is not a redox reaction. Dissolving NaCl isn't a redox reaction either.

Comment: Teacher consider H as an atom in HCl molecule but separate as an ion in water and Cl atom gained electron from H to form negative ion ,accordingly H loose to Cl

Comment: Do you mean  in your above  comment  Dissolving HCl  or  Nacl isn't a redox  reaction ?

Comment: :( neither are redox reactions.

Comment: You need a different teacher! The Chlorine in HCl is already in the -1 oxidation state, dissolving it in water does not change this.

Comment: Can I consider ionization of acetic acid in water as oxidation - reduction reaction ?

Answer (score 2):

Given the dissolution of $\ce{HCl}$ gas in water:

$$\ce{HCl(g) + H2O(l) <-->H3O+(aq) +Cl-(aq)}$$

The oxidation state of all hydrogen atoms is +1 and that of all chlorine atoms is -1. Thus, nothing has been oxidized or reduced, and no redox reaction has taken place.

Comment: just to make sure ,Can I consider ionization of acetic acid in water as oxidation - reduction reaction ?

Comment: For the same reason, no, you would not. Neither acetic acid nor water are being reduced or oxidized in that process.